# Doubly linked list working improperly

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubly linked list. When I tell it to print the items in the list forwards, it works fine. When I tell it to print the items in the list backwards, it returns 300 as the last value when it should return 100. I can't find any errors in the definition of the nodes (they are defined in order) or in dubblePrev (it's a fairly simple recursive function), although I am new to pointers (and, by extension, linked lists) so I could have missed something that might seem fairly obvious. What is going on here?

Here is my code:

```
// Doubly linked list

#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
    {
        int value;
        struct entry *next;
        struct entry *prev;
    };

void dubbleNext (struct entry *e) {
    if (e != '\0') {
        printf ("%d\n", e->value);
        dubbleNext(e->next);
    }
}

void dubblePrev (struct entry *e) {
    if (e != '\0') {
        printf ("%d\n", e->value);
        dubbleNext(e->prev);
    }
}

int main (void)
{


    struct entry n1, n2, n3;
    int i;

    n1.value = 100;
    n2.value = 200;
    n3.value = 300;

    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.next = NULL;

    n1.prev = NULL;
    n2.prev = &n1;
    n3.prev = &n2;

    dubbleNext (&n1);
    dubblePrev (&n3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `dubblePrev()`, call  `dubblePrev()`, not  `dubbleNext()`.  Simply type error.

Comment: Slight niggle, `if (e != '\0')` --> `if (e != NULL)`

Comment: @WeatherVane or even just `if (e)`...

Comment: @twalberg that's what I do, yes, but strictly, `NULL` is not guaranteed to be 0.

Comment: @WeatherVane right, but I do believe the implicit conversion from pointer-type to truth-value is defined such that a null pointer is supposed to map to false, and a non-null pointer to true, even if the `NULL` macro does not specifically resolve to a zero-valued bit pattern... I could be wrong on that, though...

Comment: My point was that OP compares a pointer with a character (although it is promoted to `int`).

Comment: @twalberg, WeatherVane There can exist more than one bit pattern that is a null pointer.  All of these pointers fail the `if(ptr)` test and all of these pointers pass the `if (ptr==NULL)` regardless of the bit pattern of `NULL`.   Just like the case when there are typically 2 `double` that pass the `if (some_double == 0.0)` test: +0.0, -0.0, pointer compare may be more than a simple bit pattern compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your "doublePrev" function. Try this.

```
void dubblePrev (struct entry *e) {
if (e != '\0') {
    printf ("%d\n", e->value);
    dubblePrev(e->prev);
}
```